# Can I use routines from comdef.h, Wbemidl.h etc in D?

Tags: windows, winapi, com, d

I know to `windows.h` header, there's D's module:

```
core.sys.windows.windows
```

but about ones like this:

```
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
```

does D support them and if so, how do I import

Comment: Comdef.h is a Microsoft specific header file, designed to work well with the #import directive in its C++ compiler.  Scratch that for D.  WMI is one of those COM apis that *somebody* ought to wrap some day, similar to System.Management in .NET.  This tends to fall in the "we're waiting for your contribution" category.  Quite possible, D supports COM well enough, just work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a Windows programming guru, but I am quite sure you will have to write a wrapper around the `wbemuuid.lib` library yourself, as compilers usually do not supply it by default. 
As you know, you can use any C function from any core Windows library.

Just by looking at `Wbemidl.h` file from the MinGW project it seems like you will have lots of work to do. - You will have to wrap wbemcli.h, wbemprov.h, wbemtran.h and wbemdisp.h.

Take a look at `std/c/windows/com.d` how to do it. There are several WindowsAPI related projects, one of them is this one: http://dsource.org/projects/bindings/wiki/WindowsApi . It will help you start.

From personal perspective, I believe the best approach is to have bindings/wrappers per WindowsAPI library. In this case I would create wbemuuid package, and wbemcli, wbemprov, wbemtran and wbemdisp modules inside this package.

Finally, you most likely want to analyse [existing COM support in D](http://dlang.org/interface.html#COM-Interfaces). And Lionello's "[Modern COM Programming in D](http://lunesu.com/uploads/ModernCOMProgramminginD.pdf)" slides.